# Like Box will not accept the url for my FB Profile

Tags: unobtrusive-javascript, facebook-apps, facebook-iframe, facebook-comments, facebook-likebox

Im trying to link my facebook profile to my website , but when I put the url into the like box it gives me a message "Could not retrieve ID for the specified page. Please verify correct href was passed in."How can I fix this ?

Comment: Is it a page, or your personal profile?

Answer (score 1):

The Like Box does not work with personal profile page. You need to create a fan page or an app.